# Who is the father of Darth Vader?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, star-wars

In 'The Phantom Menace', Anakin's mother says:

> There was no father. I carried him, I gave birth to him. I can't explain what happened.

So who was his father? Was it Darth Plagueis; because quoting Palpatine:

> It's a Sith legend. Darth Plagueis was a Dark Lord of the Sith, so powerful and so wise he could use the Force to influence the midi-chlorians to create... [significant look at Anakin] ...life.

NOTE: I think it's Plagueis because that would tie all the 9 movies together (yes, that would also include the prequels hence would not disregard Lucas's work, which would have been a very difficult job to do). I say this assuming Supreme Leader Snoke turns out to be Plagueis.

Answer (score 12):

From [Scifi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9715/6006)

> From [Anakin Skywalker Wookipedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker#Skywalker.27s_possible_.22father.22)
>
> > In addition, although Darth Plagueis did attempt to influence the midichlorians to create the ultimate Sith weapon alongside Darth
> >     Sidious, the experiment was ultimately a failure, and the midichlorians, sensing the Sith's inherent malevolent intention, not only refused to do so, but in retaliation, conceived Anakin Skywalker in order to destroy the Sith once and for all.
>
> So, according to this, neither Darth Plagueis nor Darth Sidious are
>   Anakin Skywalker's father, the midichlorians really conceived him
>   without any outside direct intervention.

So he was born completely out of force and has no father according to Star Wars: Darth Plagueis Novel.

**Note**: But [Star Wars: Darth Plagueis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis) is a novel from [Star Wars expanded universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_expanded_universe). And On April 25, 2014, following the acquisition of Lucasfilm by The Walt Disney Company in November 2012, it was announced that all previously released expanded universe content would be declared non-canon and rebranded as Star Wars Legends.

Comment: So in a way , Plagueis is the reason Anakin was born right ? So in a way he was his father ? (I think it would be an incredible plot twist !)

Comment: @user3503781 one think to be noted, its from  Star Wars expanded universe. And we don't know if its still applicable or not

Comment: That is what I thought , but I just hope that if this theory is not true , Supreme Leader Snoke turns out to be someone totally unexpected...

Comment: So midichlorians decided the dark side was suddenly bad and wanted to destroy the sith? Midichlorians are now sentient?

Comment: I hope the midichlorians create a new Jedi generation next, because I'm​ really hoping for epic Jedi vs Sith battles in the future.

Answer (score 6):

- According to New Disney canon (which basically did away with any Midichlorians in works not inherited from George Lucas), the Force "stiked back" at Darth Plagueis.

  > Darth Plagueis had once remarked that “*the Force can strike back*.”  (*"Tarkin", by James Luceno*)

  It's left un-clarified how it did so, but since we know that Disney canon freely borrows from EU, it's not impossible to assume that this statement referred to EU's most famous "force striking back" at Plagueis, and creating The Chosen One Anakin Skywalker.
- Further, Disney canon in the form of [Starwars.com Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/anakin-skywalker-biography-gallery) confirms this in a way, stating:

  > Anakin was powerfully attuned to the Force since birth -- **some believe his supernatural birth is proof that he was conceived by the will of the Force**.

Not exactly 100% full confirmation, but coupled with the Sith statements above,seems to be enough evidence for me even ignoring EU/Legends decanonized "Darth Plagueis" book.

Comment: So is my theory correct or am I wrong ?(Because I don't know what is canon anymore !)

Comment: @JarJarIsSnoke - 100% of info in this answer is new canon. However, it only HINTS at an answer, not proves it. That says, since it "fully" (changing Midichlorians to Force) agrees with OLD canon, which does prove it, I tend to thinks that's the truth.